# Style both points and multipolygons simultaneously Leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I was working on an application in which you can show `points` on a map. To improve the application, I added the functionality the show `multipolygons` as well.

I've created a dropdowmenu where you can select a dataset. One is a dataset containing stores (points), and the other contains precincts (multipolygons). Everything works fine and I can show either points or polygons on the map.

Because I build the application to only show points first, I've only styled the points (see code below).

```
var myStyle = {
"color": "#ff7800",
"weight": 5,
"opacity": 0.65
};

     window["mapDataLayer"] = L.geoJson(geojson, {
        pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
            var markerStyle = { 
                fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.Fastfoodketen),
                color: "#696969",
                fillOpacity: 0.6,
                opacity: 0.9,
                weight: 1,
                radius: 8
            };
            return L.circleMarker(latlng, markerStyle);
        },
         onEachFeature: function (feature, layer){
           layer.on({
                click: function showResultsInDiv() {
                    var d = document.getElementById('tab4');
                    d.innerHTML = "";
                        for (prop in feature.properties){
                        d.innerHTML += prop+": "+feature.properties[prop]+"<br>";
                        }
                    $('.nav-tabs a[href="#tab4"]').tab('show');
                }
            }); },
         style: myStyle
    }).addTo(map);
```

Now I want to style the polygons. **How can I alter the code above to include polygons as well?**

I thought it would be a good way was to include an if/else loop to check if the geometry was a point or a multipolygon and then direct to the appropriate styling. However, I don't know how to check if a geometry is a point/polygon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is covered by the [Leaflet documentation on GeoJSON options](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#geojson-option) (emphasis mine):

> `pointToLayer`: A `Function` defining how GeoJSON **points** spawn Leaflet layers.[...]
>
> `style`: A `Function` defining the `Path` options for styling GeoJSON **lines and polygons**, [...]

You can see examples of this in the [Leaflet tutorials for GeoJSON](http://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson.html)

Comment: I've checked the Leaflet site before, but when I implement `style`, it changes both my points (which I don't want to change) and multipolygons. I've edited my question with new code.

Comment: Ok that's good to know! But how do I check if a feature is a point or a polygon?

Comment: `if (feature.geometry.type === 'Point') {...}`. Do have a look at the [GeoJSON spec](http://geojson.org/)

Comment: Great, this works flawlessly! I've used something like that before, but couldn't get it to work. Thanks a lot!